# <a> tag cannot be clicked because onclick doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have come across very annoying problem which I was desperate to solve almost a day and half. Does anyone of you know why my  tag is not clickable?

I tried to set its CSS z-index setting to overlap every layer that is on my website because I thought it might be one of the reasons why it's not working. Then I quickly came to realize it was quite pointless and there is a problem with Javascript somewhere.

Here is the code in HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="team-about">
        <div class="team-content">
            <h1 class="centerText">our team</h1>
            <div class="slideshow">
                <div class="cards">
                    <div class="card" style="opacity: 0;">
                        <img src="pics/contact-pics/han.png" alt="" width="150px">
                        <h1>VH<br>producer</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate, corrupti facere eaque ea perspiciatis nobis neque reprehenderit. Ratione maiores distinctio soluta, aspernatur earum similique? Modi amet autem dicta nesciunt cum.</p>
                    </div>
                    <?php 
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mysqlTeam)){
                    $nameteam = $row['member_name'];
                    $namephoto = $row['member_photo'];
                    $memberdescription = $row['member_description'];
                    echo "<div class='card'>
                        <img src='pics/members/$namephoto' alt='' width='150px'>
                        <h1 style='opacity: 1;'>$nameteam</h1>
                        <p style='text-align: left;'>$memberdescription</p>
                    </div>";
                    }
                    ?>
                    <!--  HERE ARE THE TAGS -->
                    <a onclick="return addSlide(-1);" id="prev">&#10094;</a>
                    <a onclick="return addSlide(1);" id="next">&#10095;</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="scripts/about.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here is the code in JS:

```
 //THIS IS ABOUT.JS
 //THIS CODE IS ON THE BOTTOM OF THE .JS FILE

 var slideIndex = 1;
 addSlide(slideIndex);
 function addSlide(n)
 {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
 }

 function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
 }
```

I was thinking if it isn't the problem with .js file being on the bottom of the HTML code but once I moved it up in  section, the code for slides in .js doesn't work.

**NOTE: These  tags can only be seen when width of the device is 500px or less. That includes mobile devices.**

Comment: By "not working" are you getting any errors in the console (F12 to open dev tools), or is just nothing happening?

Comment: Just like you said, nothing is happening. No errors, no warnings, anything that could help me fix this problem.

Comment: If you mean the first card that has the opacity value set to zero, it should be like that for the desktops. Mobiles have it removed automatically by .js code. So the first card you should see, it's not actually there when resizing the browser. I know it doesn't make any sense, but it's happening.

Comment: Without the CSS the code [works as it is](https://jsfiddle.net/v27y9zc4/2/) ..?

Comment: I have two members registered currently registered in my database. They all have their name, description and photo. The first 'card' which opacity is set to zero doesn't even matter because it is not there, it is deleted after refreshing the mobile device (not deleted when you are on desktop). Since there's no card because it's deleted, I grab all the cards using PHP and MySQL from my database.

Comment: Have you checked the source code, that the PHP-created cards are rendered to the markup? If there's only a single card, `slideIndex` stays at 1, and no errors will occur.

Comment: It seems to be rendered correctly, I cannot see any problems in rendering.

Comment: I just did the same thing as you did - add the cards manually instead of getting them from the database. Guess what, it doesn't work as well. So since it worked for you with no CSS included, there is a problem somewhere with CSS line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the problem was in CSS, I already found it. I accidentally set `pointer-events: none;` for my cards' box because I was creating slideable picture preview for desktop. This prevented me from clicking on anything inside the div. I just restarted it for mobile devices.

For some guys out there struggling with similiar issue, try to set higher `z-index` or chceck if you set `pointer-events: all;` so you don't make the same mistake.